# python pandas: access the element of the list in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

i have a problem with accessing list element in DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

d=DataFrame({'pos': {0: [0.11,0.14,0.46], 1:[1,2,3]},'n': {0: 2.0,1:1}})
```

Column 'pos' contain a list.
I need to calculate new column with 'n'-th element of the list in 'pos'-column
In this case: 0.46, 2.

I think it would be smth like this:

```
d[u'new column']=d.pos.apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

but instead x[0] i need x[d.n].

I read manual and search the forum but havn't found anything. I fill it smth obvious, but i stucked. Help me, please.

Comment: Your code generates an empty dataframe, can you fix your dataframe construction code, thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you better init you dataframe the following way

    d=DataFrame([{'pos': {0: [0.11,0.14,0.46]},'n': {0: 2.0}},
               {'pos': {1: [0.1,0.4,0.6]},'n': {1: 1.0}}])

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3 as this will determine how to access the first value in the dict, also storin a dict with value as a list is painfully horrible

Comment: If using python 3 then using the dataframe construction code from Tom Ron then this works: `def func(x):
    return next(iter(x.pos.values()))[int(next(iter(x.n.values())))]
d['new column']=d.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)`

Comment: have fixed DataFrame. Sorry, it was the end of long day.

Comment: I'm using python 2. It looks like pain. :) I have fixed the code: fist row is int, second is list.

Comment: def func(x):
    return x.pos[int(x.n)]

d['new column']=d.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1). This works fine. Great thanks to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all! This works fine:

```
def func(x): 
    return x.pos[int(x.n)]

d['new column']=d.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)
```